# How to activate motors using Raspberry and L289n

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have some troubles with my Raspberry Pi3B+. First of all, I want to control 2 motors using the Raspberry Pi and the L289n MotorDriver. My main problem is that the motors won't start...
If I use my multimeter, it says that there is no electricity that arrives on the motors. However, it may be the code or even the circuit, I don't really know. 
So I decided to ask her and upload not only my code but also my circuit as a picture. Maybe you can help me.

[image]

```py
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

#Motor 1
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(27,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(17, 0)
GPIO.output(27, 0)


#Motor 2
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(23, 0)
GPIO.output(24, 0)

#Control Motor 1
GPIO.output(27, 1)
GPIO.output(17, 0)

#Control Motor 2
GPIO.output(23, 0)
GPIO.output(24, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

in1 = 17
in2 = 27
en = 25
temp1 = 1

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(in1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(en, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.LOW)
p = GPIO.PWM(en, 1000)
p.start(25)
print("\n")
print("The default speed & direction of motor is LOW & Forward.....")
print("r-run s-stop f-forward b-backward l-low m-medium h-high e-exit")
print("\n")

while True:
    x = raw_input()
    if x == 'r':
        print("run")
        if (temp1 == 1):
            GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.LOW)
            print("forward")
            x = 'z'
        else:
            GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.HIGH)
            print("backward")
            x = 'z'
    elif x == 's':
        print("stop")
        GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.LOW)
        x = 'z'
    elif x == 'f':
        print("forward")
        GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.LOW)
        temp1 = 1
        x = 'z'
    elif x == 'b':
        print("backward")
        GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.HIGH)
        temp1 = 0
        x = 'z'
    elif x == 'l':
        print("low")
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(25)
        x = 'z'
    elif x == 'm':
        print("medium")
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(50)
        x = 'z'
    elif x == 'h':
        print("high")
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(75)
        x = 'z'
    elif x == 'e':
        GPIO.cleanup()
        break
    else:
        print("<<<  wrong data  >>>")
        print("please enter the defined data to continue.....")
```

If you take a look at the code carefully, you can easily understand the working. Run the script.

You will get a message regarding the default speed and direction of the Motor. This is followed by a list of commands you must use to control the motor. These commands are given below.

- r – run (to run or start the motor)
- s – stop (to stop the motor)
- f – forward (to run the motor in forward direction) – default direction
- b – backward (to reverse the direction of rotation)
- l – low (to decrease the speed to 25%) – default speed
- m – medium (to run the motor at medium speed 50%)
- h – high (to increase the speed to 75% level)
- e – exit (to stop the motor and exit Python)

Source - [Raspberry Pi L298N Interface Tutorial](https://www.electronicshub.org/raspberry-pi-l298n-interface-tutorial-control-dc-motor-l298n-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. But what is the en set on pin 25? I only use the in1-4

Comment: From source: Since we are controlling a single DC Motor, we need to use a single channel of the L298N. In order to do that, connect the ENA pin of L298N to Physical Pin 22 (GPIO25) of Raspberry Pi. Please have a look at the link to relate better

Comment: Ok. And if we use 2 Dc Motors we dont need it no longer

Comment: @DizzySailor I'm not well versed with DC motors. I can do pretty basic physical computing